# unable to import 'pymongo'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pymongo-3.x

So i learning flask web dev with mongodb. I am getting an error on the following code,

```
import pymongo
```

I am using virtualenv and the following are configured on it, obtained via `pip3 freeze`,

```
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-MongoAlchemy==0.7.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
MongoAlchemy==0.19
pymongo==2.8.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

I am getting the error `unable to import 'pymongo'` via pylint on Visual studio code.

FYI i was getting a similar error when using MongoAlchemy. I thought i'd switch and give it a go with pymongo.

```
from flask.ext.mongoalchemy import MongoAlchemy
```

I have run `python3 -m pip install pymongo` but as you may correctly guess i am getting `Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.8.1)`

How could i solve this ? Thank you.

Comment: are you using python3 everywhere? Perhaps you have installed it with `python3` and see it in  `pip3 freeze`, but are running your program with a different version of python (or even the same version, but installed somewhere else)

Comment: @lucidbrot I am using python3 everywhere. My virtualenv is using python3.7

Comment: And the virtualenv is activated?

Comment: @lucidbrot yes it is. What i have done now is deleted the virtualenv directory and reinstalled everything. I am now using 'from flask_pymongo import PyMongo'. That seems to be working but i am still getting unable to import pylint error on VsCode. Weird.

Comment: What is the Flask version you're running?
Could you try doing: `from flaskext.mongoalchemy import MongoAlchemy` and tell the result?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj Thank you. I downloaded all the latest versions via pip. Will try this and let you know. Not on my personal mac atm.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj The solution you proposed does not work. Looking at it again it looks like the library import which I initially tried but yours is flaskext which I think is a typo.

Comment: For using flask-mysql I hadd to do `flaskext` instead of `flask.ext`, so I thought it might help.

Comment: Take a look at [flake8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160207/using-flake8-in-vscode) instead if you can, it'll work with vscode and was much more stable in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

so it seems like `flask.ext..` is deprecated. so from `flask_pymongo import PyMongo` is the way to go if i want to use pymongo. As for the error vscode was showing it seems like it's related to linting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by restarting my virtualenv.

I hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score -2):

[image: unable to import 'pymongo' via pylint on Visual studio code]

Disabling linting worked for me; you can find the checkbox in settings by searching `pylint`

Comment: Please answer the question in full and only use links supplementally. See the [tour] for how to answer questions so that they are usefull into the future.