# How to use Flake8 in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, lint, flake8

My VSCode is using a locally installed anaconda environment, at the default directory, which places it in Program Files. Because of this I'm unable to install flake8 through VSCode, I get a permission error. If I update my conda environment at the local level to install flake8, does anyone know if VSCode recognize and be able to use the package then?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Usually yeah it will. But if it doesn't work for you, then you can try specifying absolute path to flake8 and enable it explicitly like so :

```
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,  
"python.linting.flake8Path": "path/to/flake8",
```

you can even specify path to your conda environment :

```
"python.condaPath": "path/to/condaenv/",
```

Comment: This worked for me - in VS, you simply open Setting, search for `flak8`, find needed path, and insert in corresponding JSON file for flake8 configuration.

Answer (score 19):

Have you tried to:

> 1. ctrl + shift + p
> 2. write "select linter" then click on it
> 3. click on flake8

Maybe that helps.

Comment: I installed Flake8 in the VS Code extension, but I don't see "select linter" via ctrl+shift+p.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will. You'll have to install `flake8` into each environment that you specify as an interpreter for a project in VSCode.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass the permission error in VSCode to install from there? I just tried installing through anaconda navigator which worked fine but VSCode isn't recognizing it, either way you answered my question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I just installed [Flake8 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.flake8) to [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as shown below. *I use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) on Windows 11:

[image]

Then, it works properly as shown below:

[image]